# Set weekend days via Exchange Service API

Tags: .net, exchangewebservices

I want to create new calendar via Exchange Service API, How can I set weekend days (sunday, saturday, ...)?

I can create calendar like this

```
var folder = new CalendarFolder(
folder.DisplayName = "New calendar folder";
folder.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
```

But there are no properties or methods I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for working hours? You can't set those options per-calendar, it's per mailbox. EWS doesn't give you a direct way to set these properties, but if you're so inclined, the format for how the config is stored is fully documented here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202895(v=exchg.80).aspx